# Can I get a subquery return more than one record?

Tags: sql, oracle10g, oracle11g

I am getting `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row` error when i turn to run the following query, Any idea how to resolve this? Or do you think I might have to write a cursor to overcome this issue? Please help!

```
SLECT DISTINCT J.NAME
 FROM Q_jobs j, xx_po x
WHERE j.name IN
                CASE
                   WHEN x.name IS NOT NULL THEN
                      (select name from xx_po)                  
                ELSE
                      (SELECT DISTINCT j.name
                         FROM per_jobs
                        WHERE j.name not LIKE '%Des%')
                END
ORDER BY J.NAME
```

Comment: What are you trying to get?

Comment: I think you need parentheses around your `CASE ... END` structure.

Comment: A sub-query that returns more than one record is a RELATION which must be JOINED to the rest of the query.

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens - only if use very broad definition of a JOIN. For example, would you consider the following a JOIN:  `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE somefield < ALL(SELECT anotherfield FROM ...)` ?

Comment: @PM77-1: Correction: In the example you reference, the ALL is just a rewording of a scalar using the MIN() aggregate function.

Comment: @PM77-1: Modern engines offer much now syntactic sugar that hides common complicated join patterns

Comment: Can you actually use CASE to switch between 2 complete subselects like this, or is CASE only used to swap parts of an expression?

Answer (score 1):

Try this )

```
SELECT DISTINCT J.NAME
 FROM Q_jobs j, xx_po x
WHERE (x.name IS NOT NULL and j.name IN (select name from xx_po)) 
    or (x.name IS NULL and j.name IN (
                         SELECT DISTINCT j.name
                         FROM per_jobs
                         WHERE j.name not LIKE '%Des%'))
ORDER BY J.NAME
```